# Is there a way to access k8 pod metadata(specifically pod name) in helm template file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

Basically i am doing a poc where i need to get the k8 pod name and trim the prefix part (to be specific ) the release name of the deployment . For example , my deployment name is alpha and app name is beta so the pod name comes to be something like

"alpha-beta-23jgoi-23ngo" .

Now i want to trim the podname inside my helm yaml file to something like
"beta-23jgoi-23ngo".**Note that i want to store this value as part of some other variable in values.yaml , not modify the pod name itself**

Can anyone suggest something . So far i have been able to get the pod name using fieldref (metadata.name) , in helm yaml file but not able to pass it to some tpl file to trim. Thanks in advance

Comment: The Pod doesn't exist yet when the Helm chart runs (your chart creates a Deployment, and a standard Kubernetes controller creates some number of Pods from it).  Do you actually need to create a different value per replica?  Can you do the string manipulation in your application code or container setup somewhere?